# Merge files using transpose logic in PHP

Tags: php, merge

I have two csv files

file1
Apple,Mango,Banana

file2
2,3,4,5

I want the output file to be:
Apple,Mango,Banana,2
Apple,Mango,Banana,3
Apple,Mango,Banana,4
Apple,Mango,Banana,5

How can I do this using PHP?

```
<?php
$csv1 = file('Book2.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$csv2 = file('Book1.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$output = fopen('output1.csv','w');

foreach ($csv1 as $value_csv1) {
    foreach ($csv2 as $value_csv2) {
        fwrite($output, $value_csv1 . ',' . $value_csv2 . PHP_EOL);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: .csv file are comma separated values

file1
Apple, Mango, Banana,

file2
2, 3, 4, 5

where are the commas(',') positioned?
is this correct? in your example do not have comma(,)

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the post and added the missing commas

Answer (score 0):

Reading the file by parts is much better than reading the whole file and storing it in memory. Try this:

```
<?php

$file1 = fopen("Book1.csv", "r");
$file2 = fopen("Book2.csv", "r");
$output = fopen("output1.csv", "w");
$line2parts = array();

while (!feof($file1)) {
    $line1 = "";
    $line1 = fgets($file1);
    $line1 = trim($line1);
    if (empty($line1)) {
        continue;
    }
    while (!feof($file2)) {
        $line2 = "";
        $line2 = fgets($file2);
        $line2 = trim($line2);
        if (empty($line2)) {
            continue;
        }

        $line2parts = explode(",", $line2);

        foreach ($line2parts as $line2part) {
            /* if your writing a file that is intended for a
            windows user you should append "\r\n" instead */
            fwrite($output, $line1 . "," . $line2part . PHP_EOL);
        }
    }
}

fclose($file1);
fclose($file2);
fclose($output);

?>
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

TRY TO USE fgetcsv() and file_get_contents(); assign the output to variable and write to a file.

```
<?php
    $csv1 = file_get_contents('book1.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);//apple, mango, banana
    $row = 1;
    if (($handle2 = fopen("book2.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle2, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $num = count($data);
            $row++;
            for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                echo $csv1.' '.$data[$c] . "<br />\n";
            }
        }
        fclose($handle2);
    }
    ?>

OUTPUT:

Apple, Mango, Banana ,2
Apple, Mango, Banana ,3
Apple, Mango, Banana ,4
Apple, Mango, Banana ,5
```

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Hi rm_beginners:
Using the above code, I get the following output,
Apple, Mango, Banana  (nextline)
2<br />
Apple, Mango, Banana  (nextline)
3<br />

Answer (score 0):

```
My previous example output is in the screen.

here's output to a file.

<?php
$output = fopen('output1.csv','w');
$csv1 = file_get_contents('book1.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);//apple, mango, banana
$row = 1;
if (($handle2 = fopen("book2.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle2, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            $dataX = $csv1.' ,'.$data[$c];
            fwrite($output, $dataX.PHP_EOL);
        }
    }
    fclose($handle2);
}
?>
```